# two level aggregate result show numeric(0)

Tags: r

My original dataframe is like below:

```
data <- data.frame(ID=c("AA","BB","BB","CC","CC"),TIME=c("T2","T1","T2","T1","T2"),X=rnorm(5,10,2.3),Y=rnorm(5,12,1.9)) 

data
  ID TIME         X        Y
1 AA   T2  9.309578 11.27739
2 BB   T1 10.434972 12.51784
3 BB   T2  8.535557 10.46360
4 CC   T1 11.305246 13.61831
5 CC   T2 10.325448 12.08844
```

Then I calculated the difference of rows between two levels.

```
Diff_test <- with(data, aggregate(data[,-(1:2)], by=list(ID), FUN=diff))
```

Result shown here.

```
 Group.1         X         Y
1      AA numeric(0)    numeric(0)        
2      BB -1.899415 -2.054241
3      CC -0.979798 -1.529876
```

The first row shows `numeric(0)` for the due to only one level of time exist. Is there any way I can assign value `0` to the `numeric(0)` results? So the result would be like:

```
Group.1         X         Y
1      AA         0    0       
2      BB -1.899415 -2.054241
3      CC -0.979798 -1.529876
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a `if/else` condition to return 0 for those 'ID' with only a single observation.

```
 aggregate(data[,-(1:2)], by=list(ID=data$ID), 
      FUN=function(x) if(length(x)==1) 0 else diff(x))
 #  ID         X        Y
 #1 AA  0.000000  0.00000
 #2 BB -1.899415 -2.05424
 #3 CC -0.979798 -1.52987
```

---

An option using `dplyr` is

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    summarise_each(funs(if(n()==1) 0 else diff(.)), X:Y)
#     ID         X        Y
#  (chr)     (dbl)    (dbl)
#1    AA  0.000000  0.00000
#2    BB -1.899415 -2.05424
#3    CC -0.979798 -1.52987
```

---

Or with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[,  lapply(.SD, function(x) if(.N==1) 0 else diff(x)) , 
                       by = ID, .SDcols=X:Y]
```